# "cout" chaining while performing increment and decrement produces unexpected result

Tags: c++, increment, cout, chaining, decrement

The following program includes simply increment and decrement operations. As my prediction the program should print "0 1 1 1" but it is printing "1 0 2 0" instead,but why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    cout<<i++<<" "<<i++<<" "<<--i<<" "<<i++;//this will print "1 0 2 0"
}
```

...but it works fine if I don't chain the output command like,

```
cout<<i++<<endl;
cout<<i++<<endl;
cout<<--i<<endl;
cout<<i++<<endl;
```

Even if they should work in the same way but they are producing different results. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post and pre-increment when you use `i++` it runs after the line when you run `++i` it adds before the line is executed so when you did `--i` it subtracted from `i` before the line ran for the `i++` calls.

try making them all either `i++` and `i--` or `--i` and `++i` so the results don't vary based on if they're on the same line to not.